# How do you change your account password in Uplink?

Tags: uplink

When I created my user account in Uplink, I misunderstood what it was for and actually used a password that I use for other accounts.  When I started playing again, I noticed that password was visible in plaintext right at the login screen.

I've looked around the options menus, but found no way to change your account password.  Is it impossible, or just well hidden?

Comment: +1 I was probably going to ask this question in a few hours or so, coz the exact same thing happened to me.

Comment: What Uplink build do you have?  I just tested it and the password shows up as stars for me on the 'choose agent' screen.

Comment: @SteveV. The password becomes visible whenever you log into your account then attempt to log into your employers' website.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland - Ah, I see now

Comment: And this is another reason why password reuse is bad.

Comment: @John I am ashamed of my screw up.  I've got different/unique passwords for seriously important accounts (financial, email, etc) and a couple less secure passwords for sites that I don't frequently visit.  While this is one of the less secure ones, I don't want it as easily available as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching, I have found no way to change your password from anywhere within the game.

There are no external tools to change the password other than hexediting the actual save files.

For the moment, I'm going to say **it's not worth your time to try and change it, especially if it's a valuable password.  Just delete and start again.**

By the way, Uplink doesn't delete your save files when you retire an agent, it merely moves them to a "deleted" directory, so if you're very concerned, you should delete them manually.

- On Linux your save files are located in `~/.uplink/` as `NAME.usr` and `NAME.tmp`  (replace NAME with your profile name, obviously).
- On Windows they should be located in `/Program Files/Uplink/User/` or something similar.
- I don't know where they might be on Mac.

Comment: http://www.mario-konrad.ch/index.php?page=14002 oh, it's redshirt 1 by the way

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - See the official introversion changelog (http://www.introversion.co.uk/uplink/changes.txt) - Changed in version 1.49 : Saved games are now encoded in Redshirt 2.

Comment: ah I see, in that case [this thread](http://forums.introversion.co.uk/uplink/viewtopic.php?t=36064) linking to [redshirt2.exe](http://www.uplink.co.uk/frenchfrog/redshrt2.exe) might do the trick